# Sequence of unitary operators approaching a projector

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider $U_n$ to be a sequence of unitary operators in a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. My questions are:

Q1) Can $U_n$ converge *weakly* to some projector operator $P$ as $n\to \infty$?

Q2) Can $U_n$ converge *strongly* to some projector operator $P$ as $n\to \infty$?

I think the answer is "yes" to both questions, if so, is there some simple example?

**EDIT**: $P$ is assumed to be different from the identity.

Comment: $U_n=e^{2\pi i/n}I$ converges *in norm* to $I$, which is an projection.

Comment: @Aweygan: unless $I$ is the identity $U_n$ is not unitary. It is right that the identity is a projection, but it is trivial.

Comment: Well it's the simple example that says yes, this can happen.  If you want non-trivial projections, you should state this in your question.  In any case, if you restrict your question to non-trivial projections, the answer to the second question is no, and I'm still thinking about the first question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, take $\mathcal H=\ell^2(\mathbb Z)\oplus\mathbb C$, and define $U_n$ by $U_n=U^n\oplus 1$, where $U\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb Z))$ is the unilateral shift.  Then $(U_n)$ converges weakly to $0\oplus 1$, which is a rank-$1$ projection.

For 2, this cannot happen.  For if $P$ is a non-trivial projection, there exists a non-zero $x\in\ker P$.  Thus $\|Px\|=0$, while $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all unitaries $U$.

Comment: Thank you! Q2 seems clear. For Q1: if $U$ is the unilateral shift then $U_n$ is not unitary, right?

Comment: Perhaps it's not clear what I meant.  I mean that $Ue_n=e_{n+1}$, where $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$.  If we were looking at the unilateral shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, then yes this would fail to be a unitary, but on $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ it is.

Comment: Sure! Very nice!